# How to check if $_POST is only whitespace?

Tags: php

I'd like to check if $_POST is only whitespaces in case someone hit the space bar and tried to insert empty records in the database. I'd like to do this server side. I'm already checking if it is empty with `if ( ! empty( $_POST ) )` however, this will be bypassed if I hit the spacebar and enter only whitespaces. I have a piece of code below but I was wondering how to verify all of them without having to hard code every input field name?

```
if ( ! empty( $_POST ) ) {
   if (ctype_space($_POST['first_name'])) { 
      //return to form with error
   }else{
      //insert in db
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Never assume that a superglobal element will exist.

First check the element's existence with `isset` or `empty` depending on your requirements.

Then check if fully comprised of spaces.

```
if (empty($_POST['first_name']) || ctype_space($_POST['first_name'])) {
    echo "Missing/Invalid First Name value";
} else {
    echo "Good enough";
}
```

By doing these things in this order, you avoid generating Notices.

This is lean and direct because the conditions "short circuit" (don't continue evaluating after first failure) and only two function calls are used.

It is a good idea to perform this check on each individual key in your whitelist of expected keys.  Then you can deliver specific failure alerts based on your conditional outcomes.

My overarching advice is to concentrate on refining the quality/strength of your validation and ensuring only expected values make it through your screening process and that you are offering clear failure messages to your users.

I mean, think about it, checking a non-empty/non-space-filled value doesn't do great job of validating.  If you have other fields where you expect an integer value, check for ctype_digit.  If you are validating an email value, use an email validator.

Making DRY code is important but not more important than solid/secure code.

p.s. You will largely improve the UX if you add some client-side validation.  If you are using an html form, I recommend packing your fields with attributes like `required` and `pattern`.  You can offer your users overt guidance with `title` attributes or a tooltip feature.

Answer (score 6):

Take a look at the [trim function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.trim.php)

> trim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the beginning and end of a string

```
if (!isset($_POST['first_name']) || empty(trim($_POST['first_name']))) {
    //return to form with error
}
```

With the above snipet, `first_name` :

- Have to be in the global `$_POST` variable
- Can't be a string with only whitespaces

Comment: Good, but wouldn't this trim other parts of the input too? Wouldn't a simple preg_replace on spaces be more efficient and accurate?

Comment: This only remove 'extra' whitespace at the start and the end of the string like documented. My goal to answer the question, it's the same things actually. If you have more verification to do, yes why not for regex

Comment: You can use a foreach, but the concern is each field will have differents validations rules. Your constraint is basic here but what if you want to check a range number, a datetime string format, a boolean ... I think it is clearer to validate each fields with his one rule.
 How many fields have you to validate ?

Comment: @CillianCollins - Using `preg_replace()` would definitely not be more _efficient_ since regular expressions are quite costly and shouldn't be used if it isn't necessary. Also, it's not really common that people have names etc that starts or ends with white spaces.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Accuracy is more so what I meant. Assuming that trim() takes more items out, then a simple single preg_replace() statement would actually be more efficient as it's not replacing as much, but if OP is looking to replace more than just a space then sure.

Comment: @CillianCollins - Regex is still way more expensive. If you just want to remove spaces, just add a second argument: `trim($_POST['first_name'], ' ')`. That's _way_ more efficient. No need for extra complexity. You should avoid using regular expressions for simple string manipulations, unless you _really_ have to. Not only is it slower (which, in all fairness, would probably marginal in this case) but it also adds extra complexity to your script.

Comment: @JavaNoob I don't support this answer.  Here's why: https://3v4l.org/IO0Ba

Comment: @Magnus adding a space as a character mask to trim won't change the behavior of `trim()` for the OP's intentions.  `trim()` targets all whitespace characters by default (which I'm sure you already know).

Comment: @mickmackusa - Adding a space as the second argument will make trim to only remove those kind of spaces, not all white spaces (like line breaks/tabs  etc). [Demo](https://3v4l.org/gcWNZ). My comment was to answer CillianCollins comment (about regex being better since it only removed those spaces), not as a suggestion for the OP.

Comment: @Magnus Yes.  Okay.  My angle was that I felt that was not useful for the OPs task.  I concur that regex is overkill.

Answer (score 2):

To automatically `trim` all inputs.

```
foreach ($_POST as $name => $value) {
    $value = trim($value);
    if (empty($value)) {
        // the value is empty do something with that
    }
}
```